wx.python EditableListBox Background Colour not completely visible
Does someone know how do change the Item-BackgroundColour in an EditableListBox to the default value?
OnSearch the Background color should change when the search_item is found. That actually works the first time, but if cancel the first search and repeat the search(for example search_item is "5") the Background color isn't completely visible anymore. I use win10, python 3.8.10 and wx.python 4.2.1EditableListBox
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx
import wx.adv

## Class MainFrame ##
class MainFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY,
                            title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition,
                            size = wx.Size( 500,300 ),
                            style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHints( wx.Size( 500,300 ), wx.DefaultSize )
        self.SetBackgroundColour( wx.SystemSettings.GetColour( wx.SYS_COLOUR_HIGHLIGHT ) )

        gSizer = wx.GridSizer( 1, 2, 3, 3 )

        self.m_EDL1 = wx.adv.EditableListBox(
                    self, wx.ID_ANY, u"List_1", wx.DefaultPosition,
                    wx.DefaultSize,
                    style=wx.adv.EL_DEFAULT_STYLE |
                          #wx.adv.EL_NO_REORDER |
                          wx.adv.EL_ALLOW_NEW |
                          wx.adv.EL_ALLOW_EDIT |
                          wx.adv.EL_ALLOW_DELETE)
        self.m_EDL1.SetStrings(["1a","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10",
                                "11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19",])
        self.m_EDL1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(128,128,128))
        
        gSizer.Add( self.m_EDL1, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.m_EDL2 = wx.adv.EditableListBox(
                    self, wx.ID_ANY, u"List_2", wx.DefaultPosition,
                    wx.DefaultSize,
                    style=wx.adv.EL_DEFAULT_STYLE |
                          #wx.adv.EL_NO_REORDER |
                          wx.adv.EL_ALLOW_NEW |
                          wx.adv.EL_ALLOW_EDIT |
                          wx.adv.EL_ALLOW_DELETE)
        self.m_EDL2.SetStrings(["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J",
                                "K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S",])
        self.m_EDL2.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(128,128,128))
        
        gSizer.Add( self.m_EDL2, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( gSizer )
        self.Layout()
        self.m_toolBar = self.CreateToolBar( wx.TB_HORIZONTAL, wx.ID_ANY )
        self.m_toolBar.AddSeparator()

        self.m_searchCtrl_ELB = wx.SearchCtrl( self.m_toolBar, wx.ID_ANY,
                                               wx.EmptyString,
                                               wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_searchCtrl_ELB.ShowSearchButton( True )
        self.m_searchCtrl_ELB.ShowCancelButton( True )
        self.m_toolBar.AddControl( self.m_searchCtrl_ELB )
        self.m_toolBar.AddSeparator()

        self.m_toolBar.Realize()


        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        ## Connect Events ##
        self.m_searchCtrl_ELB.Bind( wx.EVT_SEARCHCTRL_CANCEL_BTN, self.m_searchCtrl_ELBOnCancelButton )
        #self.m_searchCtrl_ELB.Bind( wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.m_searchCtrl_ELBOnTextEnter )
        self.m_searchCtrl_ELB.Bind( wx.EVT_SEARCHCTRL_SEARCH_BTN, self.m_searchCtrl_ELBOnTextEnter )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    ## Virtual event handlers ##
    def m_searchCtrl_ELBOnCancelButton( self, event ):
        
        self.m_EDL1.ListCtrl.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255,255,255))
        
        for i in range(len(self.m_EDL1.GetStrings())):
            self.m_EDL1.ListCtrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(i,wx.Colour(255,255,255))
            self.m_EDL1.Refresh()
        event.Skip()

    def m_searchCtrl_ELBOnTextEnter( self, event ):
        
        search_term = self.m_searchCtrl_ELB.GetValue()
        
        list_EDL1 = self.m_EDL1.GetStrings()
        for i in range(len(list_EDL1)):
            if search_term in list_EDL1[i]:
                self.m_EDL1.ListCtrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(i,wx.Colour(125,255,125))
                self.m_EDL1.ListCtrl.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(220,255,220))
                self.m_EDL1.Refresh()
        event.Skip()


app = wx.App()
frame = MainFrame(None)
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()

I tried
self.m_EDL1.ListCtrl.SetItemBackgroundColour(i,wx.Colour(-1,-1,-1,0))
but that doesn't seem to be the default-value...
